# How to access ModelState and and ValueProvider objects from the ActionExecutingContext object in ASP.NET CORE ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Generally in ASP.NET MVC, Inside OnActionExecuting method of ActionFilterAttribute, we would get ModelState and ValueProvider like below:

```
context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState and context.Controller.ValueProvider
```

How would we get ModelState and ValueProvider objects inside OnActionExecuting method in ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Comment: `context.Controller` should be cast to `Controller` so that you can access the properties. Usually that's the instance of `Controller` (almost the cases). But you can use `as` to safely get the controller instance and check null before using it. (the better way is `if(context.Controller is Controller controller) { //use controller in here }`)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,if you want to get ModelState,you can use :

```
context.ModelState
```

And if you want to get data in ActionFilter,you can use `context.ActionArguments["xxx"]`,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class MySampleModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestActionFilterAttribute()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [MySampleActionFilter]
        public IActionResult TestActionFilterAttribute(MySampleModel mySampleModel) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

View:

```
@model MySampleModel
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

MySampleActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class MySampleActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
            }
            var s = context.ActionArguments["mySampleModel"] as MySampleModel;
        }


        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: How would you get value provider instance from ActionExecutingContext object?

Comment: In .net core,we usually get it in [Model BInding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0),and I find no way to get it in ActionExecutingContext.